# How to determine the height of text in UITextView?

Tags: cocoa-touch, macos

What is a good way to determine the current height of the content height in a UITextView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in UIStringDrawing.h for various text measuring functions.  You probably want something like:

```
[myTextView.text sizeWithFont:myTextView.font forWidth:myTextView.bounds.width lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height;
```

If you just want to know what the text view is using, then use:

```
[myTextView contentSize].height;
```

Comment: I think you need "size" in that statement:[myTextView.text sizeWithFont:myTextView.font forWidth:myTextView.bounds.size.width lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height;